# Efficiently Follow Pinterest Users through follow API, within given time period in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, curl, pinterest

Pinterest API for follow:
LIMIT 1000 hits per hour per user access token
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/following/users/?access_token=XXXXXXXX&user=XXXXXXX

```
+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
|   userId    | usertoFollowPerHour | maxUserAvailable |
+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
| 1           |                 100 |              1000|
| 2           |                 200 |              9000|
| 3           |                 210 |               100|
| 4           |                 300 |              1100|
| 5           |                 300 |               900|
| .           |                     |                  |
| .           |                     |                  |
| .           |                     |                  |
| n           |                    n|                 n|
+-------------+---------------------+------------------+
```

Now I have to follow users for particular userID so that:
    I can follow users within limit and
    Pinterest do not block my profile

Currently, I am doing it by:
    A cron that will hit URL of the following function after every 3 hours
    A function that is:

1. calculating user to follow in one loop for Eg:

   ```
       1. let currentTime = 1:00
           and endTime = 2:00
           user to follow = 300
           timeRemaining = currentTime-endTime => 60 minutes
           300/60 = 5 => ceil(5)=5
       2. it will fetch five user in one iteration from Pinterest
       3. than it will follow them one by one in second loop 
       4. after that again it will calculate until userToFllow become 0
           300-5=295 =>  ceil(295/timeRemaining(let 59)) = 5
       5. again 1 for next user
   ```

   [image: OUTPUT]

By above logic some of our users got banned/blocked may be due to Pinterest [reason](https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/limits-and-blocks)

Please suggest me answer with a solution if possible, whether I should use multi thread or more functions to do this async. I will be happy if it can be accomplished by CodeIgniter only

Answer (score 1):

So the follow this logic in your api:

> Each app (with a unique app ID) is allowed 1000 calls per hour for each unique user token. The 60-minute window is a sliding window based on when you make your first request. If you hit your rate limit, you’ll only have to wait a max of 1 hour to get a few more requests.
>
> Every API response returns a header that gives you an update about
>   rate limiting. X-Ratelimit-Limit is the rate limit for that specific
>   request, and X-Ratelimit-Remaining is the number of requests you have
>   left in the 60-minute window.

```
X-Ratelimit-Limit: 1000
X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 890
```

Add this condition in your api response header and checking how many remaining .

```
If you exceed your rate limit for a given endpoint, you’ll get a 429 “Too many requests” error code.
```

Check for this condition response and trigger email to yourself if the http Code is 429 or log into the log file.

**PS**: Did not try this but sure it will help you to solve your problem in same way.

**Source**: [Pintrest Documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/?)

Answer (score 0):

I solved above account ban problem by adding **delay** in between two follow API call for same user the Pinterest Account as:

- Above method is following 5 users once in a minute that will lead to
  **bot activity** if all follow belongs to one account only.
- If we take maximum **300 follows per Hour** as safe limit then we can
  follow 5 users per account in a minute with **12 second gap in
  between** or random number in between 8 - 12 for more humanly like operation.
- With 12 seconds gap we can process queue for other accounts so
  that we **use resources efficiently**.
- We have to **limit max 50K follow** per account as it is standard limit.

Earlier five follows in a minute goes like this

Queue: A1,A1,A2,A3,A1

```
A1-A1-A2-A3-A1-----------------------wait till the end of the minute-------
```

Now

Queue: A1,A1,A2,A3,A1

```
A1-A2-A3---------A1-----------A1-----wait till the end of the minute-------
```

***A*** stand for Account

***-*** represent seconds

This is just an overview of basic implementation to avoid ban.